# There are two similar method, but that's not very nice looks, one of these methods it is to refactor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two similar method, but that's not very nice looks, one of these methods it is to refactor?

```
$("#campaign_title_en").on('textchange', function () {
  var slug = escapeSlug($(this).val());
  $("#campaign_slug").val(slug);
});

$("#campaign_slug").on('textchange', function () {
  $("#campaign_title_en").unbind('textchange');
});

$("#campaign_title_zh").on('textchange', function () {
  var slug = escapeSlug($(this).val());
  $("#campaign_slug").val(slug);
});


$("#campaign_slug").on('textchange', function () {
  $("#campaign_title_zh").unbind('textchange');
});
```

HTML:

```
 ul.nav.nav-tabs
   li.active
     a href="#en" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#campaign_title_pane_en, #campaign_description_pane_en"  English
   li
     a href="#zh" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#campaign_title_pane_zh, #campaign_description_pane_zh" Chinese


    .tab-pane.active#campaign_title_pane_en
      = f.input :title_en, label: _('Title')
    .tab-pane#campaign_title_pane_zh
      = f.input :title_zh, label: _('Title')
    = f.input :slug, label: 'URI', hint: 'No special characters.'
```

I use the switch in the form, the code works, but I think it's best to do refactoring, that would not be repeated.

Comment: Can you add the HTML that accompanies this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#campaign_title_en, #campaign_title_zh").on('textchange', function () {
  var slug = escapeSlug($(this).val());
  $("#campaign_slug").val(slug);
});

$("#campaign_slug").on('textchange', function () {
  $("#campaign_title_en, #campaign_title_zh").unbind('textchange');
});
```

Comment: `$("#campaign_title_en, #campaign_slug")` should be `$("#campaign_title_en, #campaign_title_zh")`

Comment: Please make sure to mark @MedhatGayed's solution as the answer if this solved your problem.